# SQL Server: Select all records from a table when values from three columns are in the columns of a previous query's result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with columns:

```
ID         Date         Code    Amt    Type
1         6/1/17         56     100.0     A
2         6/3/17         57     200.0     B
3         6/5/17         58     300.0     C
4         6/7/17         59     400.0     D
```

Based on a previous query ran, I received this result:

```
ID     Date     Code
1     6/1/17     56     
2     6/3/17     57
```

I need to run a select query that grabs all the records from the first column based on the results from the query above, as in some kind of select that would only return:

```
ID     Date     Code    Amt    Type
1     6/1/17     56     100.0     A
2     6/3/17     57     200.0     B
```

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table `TblYours`

you could write a query like below

```
select * from 
TblYours T join
(
  select ID, Date, Code from #yourQuery -- replace the inner query with your query
) T2
ON T.ID=T2.ID 
AND T.Date=T2.Date
AND T.Code= T2.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `CTE` like:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT,        Date DATE,        Code INT,   Amt DECIMAL(4,1),   Type CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,         '2017-01-06',         56,     100,     'A'),
(2,         '2017-03-06',         57,     200,     'B'),
(3,         '2017-05-06',         58,     300,     'C'),
(4,         '2017-07-06',         59,     400,     'D');

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID, DATE, CODE /* I don't know how your query looks like*/
    FROM @T
    WHERE ID IN (1,2)
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM @T
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CTE);
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+------+-------+------+
| ID |        Date         | Code |  Amt  | Type |
+----+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|  1 | 06.01.2017 00:00:00 |   56 | 100,0 | A    |
|  2 | 06.03.2017 00:00:00 |   57 | 200,0 | B    |
+----+---------------------+------+-------+------+
```

Or using a subquery with `INNER JOIN` like:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT,        Date DATE,        Code INT,   Amt DECIMAL(4,1),   Type CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,         '2017-01-06',         56,     100,     'A'),
(2,         '2017-03-06',         57,     200,     'B'),
(3,         '2017-05-06',         58,     300,     'C'),
(4,         '2017-07-06',         59,     400,     'D');


    SELECT TT.*
    FROM @T TT INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ID, DATE, CODE /* I don't know how your query looks like*/
    FROM @T
    WHERE ID IN (1,2)) T ON TT.ID = T.ID;
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+------+-------+------+
| ID |        Date         | Code |  Amt  | Type |
+----+---------------------+------+-------+------+
|  1 | 06.01.2017 00:00:00 |   56 | 100,0 | A    |
|  2 | 06.03.2017 00:00:00 |   57 | 200,0 | B    |
+----+---------------------+------+-------+------+
```